# Rehydrate redux-persist stored state from code

Tags: redux, react-redux, persist

I would like to rehydrate the whole state of my app from the Javascript code, just like auto-rehydrate works but on-demand.

Can someone show me an example of this ?

I think I need to emit a `REHYDRATE` action but I can't see how. And I am not sure it will do the same thing as auto-rehydrate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to programmatically replace your entire app state, it seems you can do what you want with a "plain-old" reducer, no need for plugins:

```
function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'APP_STATE_REPLACE':
      return action.payload.newState
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

and trigger it like this:

```
store.dispatch({ type: 'APP_STATE_REPLACE', 
  payload: { newState: { hello: 'world' } }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Benja - but I found my answer myself in fact it was really easy I just had to read the docs ;) I rely on redux-persist for storing my state, when I need to rehydrate the whole app I can just call `.rehydrate(json_blob, { serial: true })` on the redux-persist `Persistor` object I have, and voila ! This fits in fine with redux-persist logic in general (custom rehydration etc.)

Comment: Your answer is still useful in general for people not using redux-persist so I am going to upvote it. But not accepting it since it doesn't answer my question about redux-persist.